# tunneling through IPV6 network to access IPV4 VPN server?

Tags: vpn, nat, ipv6

**Scenario:**

1. I have my computer [C] at home which has public ipv6 address but only private ipv4 address.
2. My mobile phone [P] has ipv6 address and can visit ipv6 sites.
3. Now I'm running an ipv4 only VPN on [C] and I want to connect [P] with [C] through ipv6 tunnel so that [P] can visit ipv4 resources through VPN on [C].

**the network layout would be** [P]---(ipv6)---[C~~~VPN(ipv4 only)]---(ipv4)---[Remote].

I had a few searches and found that I may need NAT64/DNS64 to make it work. https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2020/02/05/ipv6-only-network-with-ipv4-access-dns64-nat64/.
However, I'm not very clear where to fit NAT64/DNS64 into my network layout above and what else elements I need to complete the layout. The questions to be answered are:

**Questions:**

1. do I need to use DNS64 on [P] so that an ipv4 only website will have an ipv6 address?
2. is the NAT64 deployed on [C]?
3. what are the methods that can be used to tunnel from [P] to [C], and how? (maybe give some code examples?)
4. do I need to modify the iptables on [C], if so, what do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

After a few searches and tries, I mange to work out the tunnel. I simply set up a socks server with
`ssh -N -D [::]:1080 localhost`
on [C] and then connected from [P] to [C] with this ipv6 proxy. The proxy works magically for ipv4 traffic also, which I don’t know how this is possible. Maybe there is a DNS64 and NAT64 already built in the current network from my ISP. If someone knows how this works, please let me know.